# Use THROW througout usp for data validation, with rollback?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that checks data up front coming from the application to make sure the application is not passing bad data. If there is a piece of bad data a THROW is used to raise an error. Is this keeping my transactions open because I am not hitting the catch block then? If so, how would I handle this?

For Example:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.lutCode WHERE ID = @CodeID)
BEGIN
  THROW('50001','Test Error',1)
END

UPDATE emp
SET emp.CodeID = @CodeID
WHERE emp.ID = @EmployeeID

IF XACT_STATE() = 1 COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

IF XACT_STATE() = -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

THROW;

END CATCH
```

The query is a lot more complex than this, and in the real query the IF EXISTS does need to be in the transaction, so putting it outside of the transaction is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would handle this a little differently ,

Do not open a transaction until you have done your validations, If validation fails raise an error in the try block and control will jump to catch block ignoring/skipping rest of the code in try block.

I have added the check IF(@@TRANCOUNT <> 0) ROLLBACK TRAN because error maybe raised during validation and in that case a transaction will never be opened.

Only if something goes wrong while the update statement is being executed the control will jump to catch block without committing the transaction and there it will be rolled back and rest of the error logging stuff will be executed.

```
BEGIN TRY

  -- do validatiion before openning transaction
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.lutCode WHERE ID = @CodeID)
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('Test Error',16, 1)
    END

-- if test passed now open transaction
 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE emp
    SET emp.CodeID = @CodeID
    WHERE emp.ID = @EmployeeID

-- commit transaction if nothing gone wrong
 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 -- Rollback transaction if something went wrong 
 -- after you opened the trasaction 

 IF (@@TRANCOUNT <> 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END

-- Other error logging
 SELECT ERROR_LINE() AS Errorline
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
       ,ERROR_NUMBER()  AS ErrorNumber .......

END CATCH
```

Comment: You should begin your TRANS as late as possible, and end it as soon as possible.  (As this answer suggests).  Of course, a single UPDATE would be atomic, so I'm not sure what is gained here by wrapping a single UPDATE with a TRAN.

Comment: @granadaCoder gains can be, cleaner error handling, restricting  invalid data, send back a user friendly error message, logging/collecting information about the errors etc. AND I would assume this is a simplified version of actual procedure , no one "with some brains" would really copy paste their actual code here would they :)

Comment: Right, but even with a artificial example, 2 fake "updates" would have been what I would have done. Update dbo.Employee (yada yada)..........and "Update dbo.Department (yada yada)".  I was speaking more to the OP just to point out the nugget.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am doing, good point. I should have put 2 updates in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

change the statement in the catch block to this:

```
if xact_state() = 1 rollback tran
```

-1 only occurs in very specific circumstances, which I dont think you're getting in your query. If you change it to rollback on any xact_state which is not 0, you should stop getting hung transactions.

Also, I don't think you are supposed to use THROW in the TRY block; just the catch block. You'd want to use raiserror() to trigger an error in the try block, and then if you choose, use throw in the catch block.

Comment: You don't want to commit changes if it returns `-1` which means an error has occurred.

Comment: Well if you're getting uncomittable transactions, that's a whole other bag of goodies which I think falls outside the scope of this question. Regardless, rolling back on -1 is NOT the correct logic.

Comment: I think the problem is that it never actually gets into the catch block because throw stops the execution immediately I believe. Though I don't see a hung transaction but Nothing gets returned when I do select 1 from the catch block so I don't know how it could ever rollback the trans.